# Xdebug: Windows + PhpStorm + Docker Desktop + CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, docker-compose, phpstorm, xdebug, docker-desktop

I created a new CodeIgniter project and need to setup debugging with Xdebug against a container running in Docker Desktop. I'm not sure how to connect Xdebug to the container given my directory structure. I get an incoming connection dialog but not sure how to map it properly.

How do you map an incoming xdebug connection when your directory structure is split between a `public` folder which is the entry point for CodeIgniter and the rest of the CodeIgniter framework code in the `server` folder? It looks like this:

[[image: 1]]

I was able to successfully create and run a docker deployment in PhpStorm:

```
Deploying 'Compose: docker'...
"C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker-compose.exe" -f D:\Projects\my-project\devops\docker\docker-compose.yml up -d proxy database opp_web
opp_database is up-to-date
opp_proxy is up-to-date
opp_web is up-to-date
'Compose: docker' has been deployed successfully.
```

My **docker-compose.yml** file:

```
version: "3"

networks:
  opp-proxy:
    driver: bridge
  default:

services:
  proxy:
    image: "jwilder/nginx-proxy:latest"
    container_name: "opp_proxy"
    volumes:
      - "dhparam:/etc/nginx/dhparam"
      - "./files/certs/:/etc/nginx/certs"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro"
    restart: "always"
    networks:
      - "opp-proxy"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"

  database:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: "opp_database"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_USER: dba
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: opp
    volumes:
      - "db_data:/var/lib/mysql"
      - "./files/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d"
    ports:
      - "23306:3306"

  opp_web:
    image: webdevops/php-apache-dev:7.4
    container_name: "opp_web"
    volumes:
      - "./files/entrypoint.d:/entrypoint.d"
      - "../../server:/app"
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: "opp.test"
      WEB_DOCUMENT_ROOT: "/app/public"
      PHP_DEBUGGER: xdebug
      XDEBUG_MODE: "develop,debug"
      XDEBUG_START_WITH_REQUEST: trigger
      XDEBUG_CLIENT_PORT: 9002
      XDEBUG_CLIENT_HOST: "host.docker.internal"
      XDEBUG_DISCOVER_CLIENT_HOST: 'false'
    depends_on:
      - database
    networks:
      - default
      - opp-proxy

volumes:
  db_data:
  dhparam:
```

When I try to map the incoming connection I would prefer to use **Import mappings from deployment** as it auto-detects the deployment but not sure what the deployment root should be set to:

[[image: 2]]

I also tried all of these files as entry points when it auto-detects the paths:

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

Assuming I use **Manually choose local file or project**, I set a breakpoint in the `server/app/Controllers/Home.php` controller (default CodeIgniter index method that returns the welcome message), the breakpoint never gets hit. But if I set a breakpoint in the `server/public/index.php` I can  step through successfully with the debugger. So there is some issue when the CodeIgniter framework gets run and doesn't debug into the `app/Controllers/Home.php` file even though the page loads successfully. How can I debug into the `app` folder?

Comment: `/app/public/index.php` and your project structure screenshot tells me that remote `/app/` should be mapped to your local `PATH_TO/server/` -- since local `app/` is on the same level as `public/`. Your docker-compose.yml tells the same: `- "../../server:/app"` -- local `server/` is mapped as a remote `/app/`

Comment: **P.S.** Path mappings for debugging are set at `Settings/Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Server`

Comment: Right. PhpStorm correctly detects the absolute path in the incoming connection (that path shown in the dialog screenshot was auto-populate by PhpStorm). So `/app/public` maps to the `public` directory locally. I can hit breakpoints in that public folder. But after the `$app->run();` line at the bottom of the file, it is going through CodeIgniter framework and no longer hitting any breakpoints under the `app` folder and yet somehow that code executes because it has to return a CodeIgniter view for the welcome message. There is a disconnect there and not sure how to bridge the gap.

Comment: Accepting `public/index.php` as the mapping on the incoming connection makes sense as it is the entry point and I tried that but any breakpoint in the app folder on a controller for example is never hit. But those files execute because the page comes back successfully to the browser.

Comment: Ignore `public` -- it's only web facing part. You need to map the root folder of the project ..  which as I understand is `server` (local path). This will cover both `server/app` and `server/public` So to repeat myself: you need to map local `server/` to remote `/app/`. See my 2nd comment -- show what you have got there.

Comment: @LazyOne It doesn't work. I added a deployment root pointing to the server folder but the accept button is still greyed out. I also added a screenshot of the other dialog above for Manually choosing a local file or project but that doesn't work either. I tried every file they list. I never hit a breakpoint for that stuff.

Comment: 1) So ... what happens when you accept the first entry from your last screenshot? 2) What do you have at the settings screen from my 2nd comment?

Comment: I added a picture of the server config. I am able to hit the public\index.php page breakpoints but not the Home controller breakpoint that returns the view back to the browser.

Comment: Sigh... one more time: You need to map your local `server/` to remote `/app/` and not just `/`

Comment: Just in case: that's not URL mapping of any kind: PHP / Xdebug does not care about URLs. It's physical path mapping: IDE needs to know how to map remote file (the file that PHP/Xdebug is using) to the local file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments from @LazyOne, I just needed to add a path for the server to be `/app/`:

[image: 1]